# How can I get the pose (coordinate) of each part for a modular robot?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

hi, everybody, I need to get the pose (coordinate) of each part (modules) for a modular robot.
I used the following codes to get the coordinate (x, y):
previousPosition_.Pos().X()

previousPosition_.Pos().Y()

But I just used this codes to get the centre coordinate of the whole robot. I do not know how to get coordinates for each module of a robot.
So, How can I do this?

Note: My modular robot consists of many modules that corresponding many  in XML file for Gazebo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17749/how-can-i-get-the-pose-(coordinate)-of-each-part-for-a-modular-robot?/) by [langong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3715/langong/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Considering your robot is your model, you can [get each link](http://gazebosim.org/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Model.html#aa0a638718d7a3e8b60727ebef48a44e0) by its name and then get the link's pose:

```
// robot is a ModelPtr
auto link1 = robot->GetLink("linkname");
auto linkPoseWrtParent = link1->RelativePose();
auto linkPoseWrtWorld = link1->WorldPose();
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [langong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3715/langong/) on 2017-11-09**:
I will try. Thanks in advance. feedbacks to you later. But I am wondering how you know we can do like this using the function? Do we need to check every plugin function of Gazebo?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-11-09**:
This answer may help: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17048/write-a-plugin-should-i-know-clearly-about-the-function-defined-by-gazebo-if-i-want-to-write-a-plugin-by-myself/#17124

**Comment by [langong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3715/langong/) on 2017-11-10**:
Good answer to my question. But here is small question "I suggest you search for keywords related to the problem", do you mean searching on Gazebo website or Google or whatever?

**Comment by [langong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3715/langong/) on 2017-11-10**:
It is working. Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-11-10**:
Yup, I mean searching on the internet in general ;)

**Comment by [langong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3715/langong/) on 2017-11-10**:
okay, Thanks a lot!